# Android design guidelines for a tab bar and segmented controls

Tags: android, design-patterns, instagram, android-tabs

I am about to start porting an iOS application to Android targeting ICS devices. The PM/designers had originally agreed that we will follow the Android design guidelines to provide users with a consistent experience. However, when I received the wireframes, I noticed  that their "tab bar" is at the bottom and that several screens have "segmented controls" at the top.

When I explained that these patterns don't follow the guidelines, they came back with a response to the effect of "Instagram for Android does it and they've been featured and have millions of users."

So I took a look at the Instagram Android app. Here is what the offending screen looks like:

[image: Tabs and Segmented Controls in Instagram]

My question is, what would this type of screen look like if it followed the design guidelines. Obviously the tabs would be on top using the ActionBar APIs. However, at that point I think that the segmented controls would only confuse the user since they would appear as a secondary tab bar. I am not familiar with any Android design patterns that mimic the iOS segmented controls in situations like this. Would an ActionBar spinner containing the 2 items be appropriate here? If so, it would seem that we would not be able to keep the "NEWS" title.

Any help is appreciated.

PS. Taking a look at the offending screen with hierarchyviewer reveals that the Instagram tab implementation uses the deprecated TabHost/TabWidget and that the segmented controls are implemented via a (custom) ViewSwitcherButton class.

Comment: "Obviously the tabs would be on top using the ActionBar APIs" -- well, they'd be on top. I'd use `ViewPager` and `PagerTabStrip` or the tab indicator from ViewPagerIndicator, personally. "uses the deprecated TabHost/TabWidget" -- neither of those are deprecated. "what would this type of screen look like if it followed the design guidelines" -- if you wait a week, I think we will get an official sliding menu implementation from Google, in which case those bottom tabs probably turn into a sliding menu and your "segmented control" would be tabs. Or use https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu